# is there a native alternative to mcrypt?

Tags: php, cryptography

i need to encrypt some data but i guess mcrypt library is not native in php right? is there a secure and native alternative?

obs: i created my own solution but the performance wasn't good =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a PHP library for Mcrypt. The documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php). It should already be installed. If it isn't there are instructions in the documentation on how to install it.

Comment: so mcrypt library is a native one?

Comment: Why do you care? Is it too slow?

Comment: What do you mean by 'native'? The mcrypt library comes with PHP, but is not compiled directly into the interpreter. If you are looking for the "made by PHP" solution, then use the library. If you can't use the library for some reason, then you'll have to recompile PHP and include mcrypt.

Comment: okay. it's just that i use to host my apps with third party services. wich i don't control the server. but thank you. helped so much ^^

Comment: @GregS
and yes, it is VERY slow. about 20 times slower than mcrypt. and this with a very short string. the wasted time rises in a PG. not acceptable =p

Answer (score 0):

The only native solution is the native solutions :/ You have to compile PHP for it. Alternatively, you *could* write your own solution in C and use it as an extension. I'm pretty sure those are you only options.

Answer (score 0):

mcrypt

mcrypt support  enabled
Version 2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes
Supported modes cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value

Comment: did you just copy paste your phpinfo? .-.